# bootstrap display data from mysql in table

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display my mysql rows to html bootstrap table. Database connection is working, displaying data is working, but it is not fancy as i want. I'd like to maybe save in arrayData maybe and then print this arrayData in html tag. Please any suggestions much appreciated. I want to do this easiest way and most convenient for editing later on. php code to display data :

```
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. " " . $row["lastName"]. "<br>"; /* and so on..*/
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

and this is my html code for bootstrap

```
    <table class="table table-striped">                     
<div class="table responsive">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Number</th>
       <th>Info</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>ales</td>
      <td>king</td>
      <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>love</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>code</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
        </div>
   </table>
```

EDIT: i want this, but loaded from database not manually typed :)!

[image]

Comment: what is the expected result supposed to look like? You didn't say much in your question regarding this.

Comment: sorry added picture my bad

Comment: oh, so you're looking for pagination then, is that it?

Comment: no. i want mysql data to display in this table. pagination is next!

Comment: oh, I see. Well it's not that hard really. Just place your `<table></table>` tags outside the loop and use the `<tr></tr>` and `<td>$var</td>` tags. HTML 101 stuff ;-) You can further your research by looking for "mysql html formatted table".

Comment: i am asking because i can't find anyone can you fix my code quickly? thankys for your time

Comment: _can you fix my code quickly?_ **Come on Ralph.... Get on with it..... Cant you tell this OP is in a hurry!!!!!!!** @Fred-ii-

Comment: @RiggsFolly [*How's about this one Smokey?...*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24855362/1415724) ;-)

Comment: i don't get it @Fred -ii-

Comment: you've an answer below

Comment: thanks guys,  have one more question, if i have link in database how could i use <a href to it and add name LINK to display in table thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, but again; HTML 101 here. This is stuff that every web developer or future developer needs to learn and know ;-)

Comment: i fixed it a href without " "

Comment: @Fred-ii- -ii- can you hook me up with php script for pagination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a php loop this way

```
<table class="table table-striped">                     
    <div class="table responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Number</th>
               <th>Info</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php 

....

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


        echo '<tr>
                  <td scope="row">' . $row["id"]. '</td>
                  <td>' . $row["name"] .'</td>
                  <td> '.$row["lastName"] .'</td>
                </tr>';





    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
} 
?>
       </tbody>
    </div>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks works, i have one more question, if i have link in database how could i use <a href to it and add name LINK to display in table thank you!

Comment: <td> <a href='".$row['info']."'>Link</a></td> it doesn't work with <a href?

Comment: i fixed it a href without " "

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:
( but you should really read some basic PHP )

```
<?php

echo "<table>";

// table header
echo "<tr><th>id</th><th>Name</th><th>Lastname</th></tr>";

// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td>".$row["lastName"]."</td></tr>";
}

// table footer

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: thanks works, i have one more question, if i have link in database how could i use <a href to it and add name LINK to display in table thank you!

Comment: Same as before: echo "<a href='".$row['linkfromdb']."'>Link</a>";

Comment: i copied your code and i get error 500   <td> <a href='".$row['info']."'>Link</a></td>

Comment: i fixed it a href without " "